# NSInteger to NSString mis understood

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have a question regarding `NSInteger` to `NSString`
i keep trying but with no luck.
however for some strange reason one of my `NSInteger` does but i dont know why
i have this method:

```
//Lets say loc_id = 869
-(void)addResource:(NSInteger)loc_id
{
   //[loc.chosenLocations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@",loc_id]];
   NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"addResource: loc_id:%@",loc_id]);
}
```

Results BAD

> Because its giving me: addResource: loc_id:20987787696 in the debugger of xcode

Its ment to be `loc_id:860`

when i try this with `loc_id = 8`
it works pretty well why is this strange behaviour
or what did i mis understood thanks for the tips and help.
when i use `%@` in string format it works for `loc_id = 8` but when i try to use
`%d` wich is normal useage it wil also result in `loc_id:20987787696`
how come ?

Useage of method:

```
-(IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender {
  UISwitch *switchControl = sender;
  [loc addResource:switchControl.tag] 
 }

 -(void)addSwitch:(NSInteger)aid
 {
    UISwitch *sw = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]];
    sw.tag = aid;
    [sw addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEvenValueChanged]];
    [self.View addSubview:sw];
 }

 //Data is dynamic (NSObject) but for example i will exclude the dynamic data.
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
   NSInteger *loc_id = 868;
   [self addSwitch:loc_id];

 }
```

at a point i want to insert it into the NSMutableArray as commented out above but i expect a value of 869 and it giefs me 2071894069 i want the value of the int not the memory thingy

Kind Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Use %i instead of %@ !

Comment: also tryed wont work

Comment: i get also loc_id:20987787696

Comment: The issue is that `%@` in the format will print the point to the integer not the integer is self. As @rdurand said use `%i`

Comment: NSInteger is a long value. You can check that by cmd clicking the NSInteger symbol

Comment: @Toploulou it is only a long on 64bit device, not on 32bit  devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `%li` or `@ld` instead of `%@`, and drop the `stringWithFormat:` call in the `NSLog` (it already expects a format):

```
NSLog(@"addResource: loc_id:%li",loc_id);
```

`%@` is the selector to format objects descriptions and strings. `%li` is to cast your integer to a long, and prevent an eventual compiler warning.

---

Edit :

After quite a few questions in the comment, here is another wrong thing in your code :

```
NSInteger *loc_id = 868;
```

You should not initiate `loc_id` as a pointer. Use instead :

```
NSInteger loc_id = 868;
```

---

Edit #2 :

As discussed in the chat, the issue came from the way the NSInteger value was extracted from the array / dictionary in which it was held.

Comment: @StefanvandeLaarschot what is not working, this code is correct.

Comment: @StefanvandeLaarschot make sure you're really calling the method with a valid NSInteger value, and the value you expect.

Comment: @StefanvandeLaarschot please read the answer as poste by rdurand. You will see that you remove the `[NSString stringWithFormat:`. This because `NSLog` already accepts a format.

Comment: bit still i expect an value of 869 but it giefs me 20987787696

Comment: That looks like a pointer to me are you sure you have copied it correctly  and that you are not passing the pointer or something?

Comment: yes i pass a pointer because the pointer is from the UISwitch tag property ?

Comment: The tag property is not a pointer. How / When do you set this property on your object ?

Comment: but the pointer is set with my loc_id inside the switchChanged event i made and cast the uiswitch

Comment: Post your code where you assign the `tag` property with the `loc_id`

Comment: Make sure *aid* has the expected value when you set the tag

Comment: So make sure you call *addSwitch:* with the correct parameter

Comment: You did not post the part where you **call** the *addSwitch:* method

Comment: Ok here's your problem : *NSInteger* should not be used as a pointer. It's a primary type. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: can set it with my dynamic data (NSObject) if it is not a pointer

Comment: NSInteger is a primary type. It's made to hold an integer value, not an NSObject. You have to find which property you need on your NSObject, and use NSIntger loc_id = myObject.myIntegerProperty;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62413/discussion-between-stefan-van-de-laarschot-and-rdurand).

Comment: i cast it like data.LOC_ID = ((NSInteger)[object[i] objectForKey:@"LOC_ID"]);

Answer (score 1):

To display your NSInteger, you don't need to format it in NSString.
Just use this code below.

```
NSLog(@" %ld",(long)loc_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use %ld or %li for integers. %@ is used for objects.

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"addResource:loc_id:%ld",(long)loc_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can cast your `Integer` to a `long` value:

```
-(void)addResource:(NSInteger)loc_id
{
    NSLog(@"addResource: loc_id:%ld",(long)loc_id);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `stringWithFormat:` in `NSLog`

Answer (score 0):

Apple Documentation

> The utility functions `NSLog()` and `NSLogv()` use the `NSString`
>   string formatting services to log error messages. Note that as a
>   consequence of this, you should take care when specifying the argument
>   for these functions. A common mistake is to specify a string that
>   includes formatting characters, as shown in the following example.

## Wrong

You don't need to add formatting strings inside NSLog:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"addResource: loc_id:%@",loc_id]);
```

## Right

Also using `%li` on **64 Bit** gives integer precision as @rdurand asnwer

```
NSLog(@"addResource: loc_id:%li",loc_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"addResource: loc_id:%ld",(long)loc_id]);
```

Gets a warning: Format string is not a string literal.

The following code works as ordered:

```
-(void)addResource:(NSInteger)loc_id
{
    //[loc.chosenLocations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@",loc_id]];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addResource: loc_id:%ld",(long)loc_id];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Comment: Why not just give the format and the parameters directly to the `NSLog` like the answer of rdurand said.

Comment: at a point i want to insert it into the NSMutableArray as commented out above but i expect a value of 869 and it giefs me 2071894069 i want the value of the int not the memory thingy